# Safe to send login credentials using HTTP and not HTTPS?

Tags: security, http, https

Is it safe to submit an HTTP POST whose body contains plaintext username and password, or is HTTPS completely necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS is required. All HTTP traffic can be sniffed.

Answer (score 1):

No, HTTP alone does not give you any security at all. If someone is able to read the network traffic, they would be able to read the credentials too.

The network traffic might also be protected separately, but you can’t control the network. But you can control your application. So HTTPS ist a must.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your answer? Should it read: "No, HTTP does not give you security at all?"

Answer (score 0):

It's never safe to send an unencrypted, plaintext username and password over a wire others have access to.

While it's safe to send *encrypted* data over HTTP, HTTPS does this for you, giving you the added benefit of [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). Given how well it stands up theoretically and in practice, it's far more compelling to use than inventing your own algorithm.